# Case_when R multi conditional logic

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I'm trying to utilize `case_when` from `dplyr` to create a categorical vector in a dataframe, but I want to see if it can be done in a cleaner way.

Example dataframe

```
structure(list(Primary.column = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Other_column1 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Other_column2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), Other_column3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to make it such that when Primary column = 0 the category is A. However, if Primary Column is 1 then I want it to query other columns based on the keyword "Other" in the other columns and whichever have 1, that determines the category.
Something like `Primary Column == 1 & (select whichever column titled "Other" has 1 in it to decide category)`
For this one this is the logic

```
If Primary Column is 1 and Other_column1 is 1 then the new column should have value B
If Primary Column is 1 and Other_column2 is 1 then the new column should have value C
If Primary Column is 1 and Other_column3 is 1 then the new column should have value D
```

In the test dataframe this is an easy solve because there are very few columns and this could be solved like so

```
test_df <- test_df %>% 
  mutate(new_column=case_when(Primary.column==0 ~ "A",
                              Primary.column==1 & Other_column1 ==1 ~ "B", 
                              Primary.column==1 & Other_column2 ==1 ~ "C",
                              Primary.column==1 & Other_column3 ==1 ~ "D",
                                 ))
```

But the true dataframe has hundreds of "Other" columns and this is not a clean solution  and I'd have hundreds of lines of code for this single variable. Not what I want.

in this example I also have a key that that tells me what columns the other columns take if primary column is 1.

Key

```
structure(list(Column = c("Other_column1 ", "Other_column2", 
"Other_column3"), Value = c("B", "C", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Is there a way to utilize the key to make it so that I don't write out 100 lines of messy code? Or are there alternative solutions to keep things clean?

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to scale for more columns. What values do you expect to return when "Primary column = 1" and you have 10 additional columns with values equal to 1? My feeling is this can be addressed if you pivot from wide to long first, but I'm not clear on your expected output.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to clarify. The expected output is the same as the "this could be solved like so" part. for me I'm more interested in the input/code used to write it and make it cleaner. If I have hundreds of extra columns that means hundreds of lines of something like ` Primary.column==1 & Other_column1 ==1 ~ "B"`. My question is how to use as few lines as possible.

Comment: Yes but what output do you expect for "hundreds of extra columns"? Do you expect letters to increment? Or will all entries be "D" even in the presence of additional columns?